# Check if "yarn install" would print "Already up-to-date" without installing packages

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

For tooling purposes, I would like to check if `yarn install` is necessary (i.e. would have an effect).

Asked differently, I'm looking for a pure mechanism to check if `yarn install` would print `Already up-to-date`.
However, I don't want yarn to actually install the packages in case the dependencies are not up-to-date.

Is there a way to achieve that, which works with most yarn versions?

Comment: Would `yarn outdated` work for you?

Comment: Alternativly `yarn check`, or `yarn check --integrity`